# PUT request does not run update

Tags: node.js, postman

I'm new to node js and I am struggling with the PUT requesting for some reason it won't update in my database. Please help, Thank you.

```
app.put('/orders/:id', (req, res) => {
    pool.getConnection((err, connection) => {
        if(err) throw err
        console.log(`Connected as id ${connection.threadId}`)

        const {orderID} = req.body
        const {status} = req.body

        connection.query('UPDATE orders SET status = "Complete" WHERE orderID = ?', [status, orderID],
        (err, rows) => {
            connection.release()

            if(!err) {
                res.send(`Order ${orderID} has been updated`)
            }
            else {
                console.log(err)
            }
        })
    })
})
```

Comment: Your SQL has a single parameter; you give it two. Start by fixing your DB statement.

Comment: Please elaborate further. I'm assuming you're talking about [status, orderID]

Comment: your lack of semicolons are disturbing! Also yes, why are you passing status if it's not used in the query?

Comment: status is the column name in mysql table, i want to change the value in it

Comment: And your SQL statement has that hardcoded into it. The "?" are essentially positional parameters; you have a single positional parameter in your SQL, and pass in two params--what do you think will happen?

Comment: Finally got it done thanks for the help.